# Updating a table synchronised by symmetricds

Tags: java, mysql, classpath, h2, symmetricds

I have been working on a small project which involves synchronizing two databases using symmetric ds. One of my databases is mysql and other one is h2. I want my program to update h2 database at the press of click. However the update function generates an error something like:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Error creating or initializing trigger 
"SYM_ON_I_FOR_DBTRGGR_CRS_LCL" object, class "org.jumpmind.symmetric.db.h2.H2Trigger", cause: "org.h2.message.DbException: Class ""org.jumpmind.symmetric.db.h2.H2Trigger"" not found [90086-176]"; see root cause for details; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO passenger VALUES(1, 'Person1', 20, 'City1', 'City2', 1); [90043-176]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:344)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:167)
    at org.h2.schema.TriggerObject.load(TriggerObject.java:77)
    at org.h2.schema.TriggerObject.fireRow(TriggerObject.java:167)
    at org.h2.table.Table.fireRow(Table.java:935)
    at org.h2.table.Table.fireAfterRow(Table.java:925)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:162)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:115)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:79)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:254)
    at

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcStatement.java:132)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcStatement.java:117)
    at h2Connector.UpdateLocalDB(dataBaseManager.java:105)
    at h2Connector.<init>(dataBaseManager.java:34)
    at dataBaseManager.main(dataBaseManager.java:8)
Caused by: org.h2.message.DbException: Class "org.jumpmind.symmetric.db.h2.H2Trigger" not found [90086-176]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:167)
    at org.h2.util.Utils.loadUserClass(Utils.java:672)
    at org.h2.schema.TriggerObject.load(TriggerObject.java:70)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Class "org.jumpmind.symmetric.db.h2.H2Trigger" not found [90086-176]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:344)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jumpmind.symmetric.db.h2.H2Trigger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.h2.util.Utils.loadUserClass(Utils.java:665)
    ... 13 more
```

I saw a similar post https://sourceforge.net/p/symmetricds/discussion/739236/thread/8a54e2ec/
which stated that "Try this from the SymmetricDS home directory. The H2 database needs SymmetricDS libraries for the java triggers." and guided to use the command

```
java -cp web/WEB-INF/lib/*:lib/h2-1.3.176.jar org.h2.tools.Console
```

I tried to run my code using this but unfortunately couldn't figure out.

Here is my h2 (Local Side) properties file:

```
engine.name=CRIS_Local-01
db.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.url=jdbc:h2:CRISDB;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=60000
db.user=sa
db.password=
registration.url=http://localhost:31415/sync/CRIS_Server-00
group.id=CRIS_Local
external.id=01
job.routing.period.time.ms=5000
job.push.period.time.ms=1000
job.pull.period.time.ms=1000
```

Here is my mysql (Server Side) properties file:

```
engine.name=CRIS_Server-00
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/PassDB?tinyInt1isBit=false
db.user=root
db.password=passwd
registration.url=
sync.url=http://localhost:31415/sync/CRIS_Server-00
group.id=CRIS_Server
external.id=00
job.purge.period.time.ms=7200000
job.routing.period.time.ms=5000
job.push.period.time.ms=1000
job.pull.period.time.ms=1000
auto.registration=true
initial.load.create.first=true
```

Here is my java code to establish connection:

```
h2Connector(){
        stmt = null;
        con = null;
        try{
            Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/Downloads/symmetric-server-3.10.2/tmp/h2/CRISDB;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=60000", "sa","");
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            System.out.println("Connected to h2 Succesfully!");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 Passenger psg = GivePassenger(1,isOccupied);
        System.out.println(psg.Name);
        UpdateLocalDB(psg);
}
```

Here is my `UpdateLocalDB(Passenger psg)`

```
public void UpdateLocalDB(Passenger psg){
        String query = "";
        query = "INSERT INTO passenger VALUES(";
        query += Integer.toString(psg.PNRNo) + ", ";
        query += "'"+psg.Name+"', ";
        query += Integer.toString(psg.age)+", ";
        query += "'"+psg.start+"', ";
        query += "'"+psg.end+"', ";
        query += Integer.toString(psg.seat) + ");";
        System.out.println(query);

        try{
            stmt.executeUpdate(query);
            System.out.println("Updated Succesfully!");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The Query part works fine
PS : I am new to SymmetricDS

Answer (score 0):

There's missing symmetricDs jar: `symmetric-db-YOUR_VERSION.jar` on the classpath of the application synchronising the h2 database.

Comment: can you please elaborate. I have a ```lib``` folder in the same folder where my Java file is stored which contains the jar file you specified. I tried to run my pogram using the following command ```java -cp ".:./h2-1.3.176.jar" -cp ".:./lib/symmetric-db-3.10.2.jar" dataBaseManager```

Comment: Here’s you can instrument your program to print all dependencies and find out if the jar has been included to the class path or not: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-print-out-the-current-project-classpath/

Comment: A temporary solution i found was to do the process while bin/sym process is running